# P value calculation for Anderson Darling normality

Tags: p-value, anderson-darling-test, c++

For p-value calculation I use (in c++) following equations I found on the internet

```
    double ADs = AD*(1+0.75/double(n)+2.25/(double(n)*double(n)));
    double ADs2 = ADs*ADs;

    if (ADs >=0.6)
        p = exp(1.2937 - 5.709*ADs+ 0.0186*ADs2);

    if (ADs <0.6 && ADs > 0.34)
        p = exp(0.9177 - 4.279*ADs - 1.38*ADs2);

    if (ADs < 0.34 && ADs >= 0.2)
        p = 1 - exp(-8.318 + 42.796*ADs- 59.938*ADs2);

    if (ADs < 0.2)
        p = 1 - exp(-13.436 + 101.14*ADs- 223.73*ADs2);
```

The problem with the equations is that it somehow do not work in some cases. For example, I have 10k dataset with AD = 306 resulting into p-value 0.21 which is in my case when I make histogram obviously wrong.

Minitab gives me **the same AD value** but different and correct p-value=0.

The question - is the **equation** `p = exp(1.2937 - 5.709*ADs+ 0.0186*ADs2);` **correct**?
Or is there any other way how to calculate p-value?

[image: histogram of my trial data]

For example, what I also found on Scilab's pages is something like this (but I dont use it since I dont understand that).

```
z=cdfnormal(-sort(-X),mean(X),standev(X))
14  a=(-sum((1:2:(2*n-1))'.*(log(z)+log(1-z(n:-1:1))))/n-n)*(1+(0.75+2.25/n)/n)
15  pv=1-cdfjohnson(a,"B",3.9667391,1.4859832,0.1043856,3.7372864)


//https://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/casci/source/tree/master/macros/cdfjohnson.sci

function Y=cdfjohnson(X,s,a,b,c,d)

19  elseif s=="B"
20    Y=zeros(X)
21    i=((c<X)&(X<(c+d)))
22    if or(i)
23      Xi=X(i)
24      Y(i)=cdfnormal(a+b*log((Xi-c)./(c+d-Xi)))
```

Comment: These equations are approximations.  Because there is no point to conducting this test with large datasets--5000 is often considered the largest size to which one might apply it--there's no surprise the approximations fail in your case.

Comment: whuber - thank you for response, this is what I suspect. But Minitab has to calculate it somehow..

Comment: Would you advise another normality test that can be useful for 5000+ data?

Comment: No, for the same reason as before: distributional tests of large datasets are pointless.